# Slickgrid Too Wide in Table Cell

Tags: slickgrid

When a Slickgrid is added to a *table-cell* styled *div*, the grid becomes excessively wide unless a maximum width is specified for that *div*.  The grid also seems to gain a phantom column to the right.

Is it possible to cause Slickgrid to only occupy necessary space in that type of layout?

http://jsfiddle.net/ericjohannsen/uMQH2/3/

**UPDATE**

I noticed the following HTML generated

```
<div class="slick-header-columns" style="left: -1000px; width: 2978px;" unselectable="on">
```

The width is being explicitly set to a value that is way too large, even given that the left if offset -1000px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm still hoping for a proper solution, but in the mean time I was able to work around the problem by including the following code after rendering the grid

```
    grid.render();

    // Hack to fix grid width issue http://stackoverflow.com/q/12032796/141172 
    var cols = grid.getColumns();
    var numCols = cols.length;
    var gridW = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<numCols; i++) {
        gridW += cols[i].width;
    }

    $('#gc').width(gridW); // gc is the ID of the div used for SlickGrid
```

Answer (score 1):

SlickGrid requires the container to have an explicitly set size.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `forceFitColumns` property to `True`